# how to find out if mod_xsendfile is handling the transfer?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, http-headers, centos6.5

I just installed and configured mod_xsendfile on my apache2.2.15 web server (on centos6.5). Everything **seems** to be working fine except that I'm not sure it is.
I added `XSendFile On` and `XSendFilePath /path/to/downloaded/files` to the virtualhost and I changed the headers to:

```
header('X-Sendfile: '.$file);
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' $file . '"');
```

Now, using google chrome inspector I can check the headers I get from the server whenever I download a file but mod_xsendfile is getting the `X-Sendfile` header out of the way and I can't find any message re sendfile in the logs. So how do I know for a fact that the download has been taken care of by apache ?

Thanks for your help :)
Marc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-Sendfile removes X-Sendfile header. So in order to check if it works:

- Check if header **does not** exist when X-Sendfile is enabled
- Check if header exists if you disable X-Sendfile.  Your file should not load

You can watch headers with curl:

> curl -I URL

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Simple as that ! Thanks @Glueon it does help a lot !